# Could Flash AIR Desktop open onscreen keyboard on Windows?

Tags: windows, flash, air

I need to open onscreen keyboard as input for Flash AIR desktop. The application will run on public space on touchscreen monitor. So I need the app will be fullscreen and no access to other app.

I manage to use virtual keyboard on Flash to do some text input. but, it cannot be done when I need to login to facebook, because facebook open new dialog. So I can't access the textbox to use fill it using virtual keybard.

facebook login dialog on clicking facebook login in Flash AIR app
[image]

I need onscreen keyboard with minimal access. Preferable like tablet input (tabtip) on windows 8

[image]

Comment: I don't have a source for this handy, but I believe the answer here is no. AIR does not support Windows 8 Metro at all and I remember seeing several other questions regarding this exact thing. I do not believe AIR supports soft keyboards on Windows, just Android, iOS, and Blackberry.

Answer (score 1):

I know the post has been created a year ago, but I'm sure this answer might be usefull for some people who were in my case.

So to open the Touch Keyboard on Windows 8 from Air, is totally possible.

I open cmd first and then use writeUTFBytes to open the TabTip.exe (edit the path if you can't make it work)

```
var file:File = File.applicationDirectory;
file = file.resolvePath("C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe");
var v : Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>();
v.push("start C:/PROGRA~1/COMMON~1/MICROS~1/ink/TabTip.exe");                               
var nativeProcessStartupInfo:NativeProcessStartupInfo = new NativeProcessStartupInfo(); 
nativeProcessStartupInfo.executable = file;             

var process:NativeProcess = new NativeProcess();                
process.start(nativeProcessStartupInfo);
process.standardInput.writeUTFBytes(v + "\n");
```